# Python and sqlite3 : insert matrix into table

Tags: python, matrix, sqlite, sql-insert

Let's say i have this matrix:

```
[[[u'artist1'], [u'song1']], [[u'artist2'], [u'song2']], [[u'artist3'], [u'song3']]]
```

I was wondering how can i insert it into a sql table so it will look like this:

```
ID | ARTIST |SONG
-----------------
1 | artist1 | song1
2 | artist2 | song2
3 | artist3 | song3
```

I have about 1 million artists and 1 million songs i have to insert so it's just an example :P

Thanks in advance!

Source code:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
print('Opening SQL Database')
sql = sqlite3.connect('mblite_post.db')
cur = sql.cursor()
cursor=cur.execute("SELECT entity0 from r_artist_release LIMIT 500000000000000 ")
result_author = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

cursor=cur.execute("SELECT entity1 from r_artist_release LIMIT 500000000000000 ")
result_song = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]


artistlist=[]
for x in result_author:
    y=cur.execute("SELECT name FROM artist_name where id='%s'" % x)
    artistname=[row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
    artistlist.append(artistname)
songlist=[]
for y in result_song:
    z=cur.execute("SELECT name FROM release_name where id='%s'" % y)
    songname=[row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
    songlist.append(songname)



matrix2 = [[artistlist[i], songlist[i]] for i in range(len(artistlist))]

print(len(matrix2))
sql2 = sqlite3.connect('itaidb.db')
cur2 = sql2.cursor()
cur2.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (artist TEXT,song TEXT )')


for i, v in enumerate(matrix2):
    cur2.execute('INSERT INTO main VALUES (?,?)', (v[0][0], v[1][0]))
    sql2.commit()



#
#
# for ton in songlist:
#     cur2.execute("UPDATE main SET (song) values (?) WHERE id='%r'", [''.join(ton)] % integer)
#     sql2.commit()
#     integer=integer+1
#
sql2.close()
sql.close()

# artistname=[]
# for x in author:
#     y=cur.execute("SELECT name FROM artist_name where id='%s'" % x)
#     artistname=artistname.append(list(y.fetchall()))
#
# print artistname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create your list like this:

```
yourlist = [(artistlist[i], songlist[i]) for i, v in enumerate(artistlist)]
```

Then you can use a for loop to execute the `INSERT` statements:

```
for i, v in enumerate(yourlist, start=1):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (?,?,?)', (i, v[0], v[1]))
```

And don't forget to commit afterwards:

```
db.commit()
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__ getitem __'

Comment: @itailitai Does your table have more than those three columns?

Comment: i fixed this error but now i'm getting IndexError: list index out of range. I added the source code in the original post.

Comment: @itailitai The `commit()` should not be inside the for loop.

Comment: still getting [this error](https://i.gyazo.com/413f4f4cb0bddd48112317786414559b.png).

Comment: @itailitai Maybe your actual list is not in the right format? Accessing the list in your question with `v[0][0]` and `v[1][0]` works.

Comment: i guess that could be the problem, i downloaded a [huge music database](http://alexthomo.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/sqlite-musicbrainz-database.html) and i'm trying to get what i need from the database into a new one (getting the artist and the song name to be in the same columns.)

Comment: can you show me how to insert two lists into the table instead of one matrix (one is a list of artists and the other one is the list of songs)

Comment: @itailitai I updated my answer. There's something wrong with how you create your list. But loading 700 MB of data into memory isn't a good idea either way.

Comment: I'm really sorry for beign a pain in the ass for you, i changed the code to be like your updated answer but now i get : sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: never mind i fixed that by doing:
yourlist = [(str(artistlist[i]), str(songlist[i])) for i, v in enumerate(artistlist)] Thank you so much!

Comment: @itailitai You're welcome, glad I could help! In case you ever reach 15 reputation, consider giving this answer an upvote.

Comment: I will, i wanted to upvote it but i couldn't :( do you know how to convert the unicode string on the matrix to a normal string? (without the u' at the beggining)

Comment: @itailitai You answered that yourself, you can use `str()`! See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-turn-unicode-strings-into-regular-strings). In Python 3 strings are unicode strings by default.

Comment: but i still get [this](https://gyazo.com/33f4a7bf7d23313efed56fef81a613d5) in the database.

Comment: @itailitai Looks like you are still writing lists consisting of just one string to your database. Add `[0]` at the end of all `[row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]` statements. Or better yet, use `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, i don't want to bother you any more, You have done more than enough :) i'll find the problem sooner or later